Gradle exclude dependency using regex
I have a project from which I need to exclude old version of AWS SDK in aid of new version.
I'm using the following instruction to do so, because I don't know exactly how many and where the old version is pulled (we use several configurations).
configurations {
  all*. exclude group:'com.amazonaws'
}

things work perfectly until here...
from now I need to use extended-sqs library but it uses the groupId com.amazonaws which is the same than the old AWS SDK version.
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>amazon-sqs-java-extended-client-lib</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
    <type>jar</type>
  </dependency>

So the question is: how do I exclude from exclusion where name is like 'amazon-sqs-java-extended-client-lib' ?
I was wondering if I could mention the module name using regular expression, but didn't find such feature...
Gradle version : 7.6.2
